# How to create contacts on SIM card/internal memory?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, contacts, stock-android

I'm trying to add new contacts on a phone, but I can only create Google contacts. I really don't want to hand over data to a company that has no real understanding of the meaning 'privacy'.

I just want to create contacts on my SIM card or internal phone memory. On other phones that's possible but for some reason it's not possible anymore.

*edit*

My phone is a Motorola Moto E with Android 4.4.4

*edit 2*

interestingly, on my Sony Xperia Z, (same Android version...more or less), I can create a contact on my phone. This is weird.

Comment: You may want to add your phone manufacturer and model, since different manufacturers use different dialers, which means the answers can vary.

Comment: @onik edited accordingly. But it looks like the default contacts application.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion: have a look at [MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount) from FJ Softwaredevelopment.

> This app does represent a local contact account. This is helpfully for devices without local contact account (f.e. Nexus series) if you don't want to sync your contacts with Google servers. These contacts can be synced then f.e. with MyPhoneExplorer to your PC.